# TestFlight: invalid app token?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testflight

I've been using TF for a long time, until recently when I upload the build, I got:

[image: Invalid App Token]

I'm not sure what the problem is, I did have that `[TestFlight takeOff:@"xxx"]` code in the app delegate. Did I miss something? If I choose to 'Ignore and Continue' it can let it through, but still, there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Perhaps you have changed the bundle ID of your application?

Comment: @Filip No I haven't changed it, thanks anyway.

Comment: You'd be better ask the TestFlight support for help. It should be enough to use takeOff:"appID" with most recent TestFlight SDK version, so I guess everything is correct on your side.

Comment: Since you've been using TF for a long time, did you make the change from team token to app token?  They changed that a little while back, but it was grandfathered for a while.

Comment: @gaige Yes, the weird thing is, another project of mine does not have that code (ie `takeOff:...`) at all but I could still upload it to TF, I did change it to use app token but still has the same problem.

Comment: i don't understand how they're detecting app tokens?

Comment: @hzxu just to be clear, even though it complains, you have not seen any issues right?